# How can i implement channel 1 to the code i have written? Note: i want to display notifications at certain times

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create notifications that pop up at certain times by getting the time from the phone. The tutorials i am following are outdated and now i need to add channels to my app for the notifications to show before i add any more or customize them. I created a class named channels and with two channels in there. How can i add those channels to my notifications?

```
public class channels extends Application {
    public static final String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    public static final String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannels();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannels() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_1_ID,
                    "Channel 1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel1.setDescription("This is Channel 1");
            channel1.enableVibration(true);
            channel1.setLightColor(220);

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_2_ID,
                    "Channel 2",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );
            channel2.setDescription("This is Channel 2");

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
}
```

Code with notifications in class activity I want to use:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_holter);
        //alarm
        AlarmManager Pop_Time = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

      Intent intent = new Intent("action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION") ;
      PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      Pop_Time.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HolterActivity.class);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(HolterActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder (context);

            Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle("Demo App Notification")
                    .setContentText("New Notification From Demo App..")
                    .setTicker("New Message Alert")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it with the builder (still checking for android version) :

```
builder.setContentTitle("Demo App Notification")
                .setContentText("New Notification From Demo App..")
                .setTicker("New Message Alert")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    build.setChannelId(CHANNEL_1_ID);
}
Notification notification = builder.build();
```